# Is there any more documentation available for the numpy.f2py.compile() function?

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

All I've been able to find is the short blurb at the end of [this page](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/usage.html). I am trying to reproduce the functionality of the `f2py -c` command line command within python, but I'm having some trouble using the `numpy.f2py.compile()` to compile a subroutine with a signature file which has dependencies in separate files. If there's not extra documentation, how does one figure out how to use it?

Comment: Just google searching "numpy f2py compile" and clicking the very first link and scrolling down to the part at the bottom about compile pretty much told me what I need to know about it.  There's even an example.  The only thing that would be stopping me is that I don't write fortran.

Comment: @Delta_G that search result is exactly the link that I included in my question. It does not include information on how to use signature files or deal with dependencies on other .f files (which is apparently different than using `f2py -c`).